# AspectJ Pointcut matching pattern

Tags: java, aspectj

I've written a pointcut that will call an around advice on the execution of a certain method.

However, I'd like to understand exactly why the final pattern I used works, but the initial pattern didn't.

The initial pattern that I used (which didn't work) was:

```
pointcut timeIt() : execution(* *.AuthFilter.filter(..));
```

The pattern that works is:

```
 pointcut timeIt() : execution(* *..*.AuthFilter.filter(..));
```

Trying to Google the difference between `*.` and `*..*.` has proved somewhat challenging. If someone could provide either an explanation or a resource that explains the difference I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is explained by the documentation:

[AspectJ Type Patterns](https://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/progguide/quick-typePatterns.html)

> An embedded * in an identifier matches any sequence of characters, but
>   does not match the package (or inner-type) separator ".".
>
> An embedded .. in an identifier matches any sequence of characters
>   that starts and ends with the package (or inner-type) separator ".".

Basically, when used at the package level, `..` means any sub-packages.

Your first expression only matches if `AuthFilter` is in the second level, for example, `org.AuthFilter`, but it would not match `org.security.AuthFilter`, in this case you would need `*.*.AuthFilter`.

Your second expression is matching `AuthFilter` wherever it is. It does not matter the package and sub package it is in.

[@AspectJ cheat sheet](https://blog.espenberntsen.net/2010/03/20/aspectj-cheat-sheet/)

Comment: BTW, this also means that you do not need `*..*.AuthFilter`, but `*..AuthFilter` suffices.

Comment: Thank you, that's a great explanation, and thanks for the link